# Change Boolean variable into an ActionEvent Java

Tags: java, boolean, actionevent

I have a method that generates a `JPanel` with one checkBox. The method has 3 parameters, one of them is a `Boolean` value that is null. When I use the `Boolean` parameter into `ActionEvent`, the system don't recognize it. Also, I use if look because I want that the user could select and unselect the checkBox. Unfortunately, the system never enter when checkBox isSelected. Could you help me, please?

```java
private JPanel getThirdPanelBox(String elementList, String title, Boolean valueMant) {
    JPanel thirdPanelBox = new JPanel();
    thirdPanelBox.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    thirdPanelBox.add(new JLabel(elementList), BorderLayout.CENTER);

    JCheckBox elementListCheckBox = new JCheckBox();
    elementListCheckBox.setSelected(false);
    elementListCheckBox.addActionListener(actionEvent -> {

        if (elementListCheckBox.isSelected())
            valueMant = true;
        else
            valueMant = false;
    });
    thirdPanelBox.add(elementListCheckBox, BorderLayout.WEST);
    return thirdPanelBox;
}
```

Comment: a boolean is just that. You can add an actionlistener to the checkbox, instead, if that is what you are trying to do.

Comment: Please try to rephrase your question,  update description like "the system don't recognize it. "(what you mean recognize it?), "Also, I use if look "(what is if look?), "the system never enter"(never enter what?, do you mean `elementListCheckBox.isSelected()` never return true?)

Comment: Sorry, I'm new in Java. The programs shows error when I use the parameter valueMant into the if statement: valueMant=true, and also in the else statement: valueMant=false.

Comment: In addition, when I runs the program, never takes elementListCheckBoc.isSelected()=true.